# Why do some ionic compounds form in the NaCl structure vs the CsCl structure?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Everything else the same, I'd expect two monoatomic ions to form an ionic structure in the CsCl structure because with more atoms bonded to each atom, it would seem to be more stable.  And yet I believe the alkali halides tend to form in the NaCl structure more often -- and even CsCl will reform into the NaCl structure if heated high enough.

In the simplest ionic compounds (monoatomic), what are the main reasons why some form in one structure vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure in these cases is determined by the relative sizes of the ions. Caesium and chloride have very similar ionic radii (174 and 181 pm, respectively), whereas sodium and chloride are very different (102 and 181 pm).

Comment: So the reason is that there isn't enough room in compounds with 2 very differently sized ions to pack them in tightly with the CsCl structure?  And so because bond strength is inversely proportional to distance, it is more favorable to pack into a structure with less bonds per atom?

Comment: @user1833709 That's right.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical example of the application of the 1st Pauling’s rule, also known as "the radius ratio rule".

This rule states:
"Each cation is surrounded by anions forming a coordination polyhedron; the cation-anion distance is defined by the summation of their ionic radii and the cationic coordination number by the ratio of the ionic radii; the coordination number defines the number of atoms coordinated by the atom at the centre of the polyhedron"

So consider the halogen clorides and their ionic sizes (Rc: cationic radius; Ra: anionic radius; exp: experimental values; calc: calculated values); given that for Pauling's rule when Rc/Ra= 0.414 – 0.732 you have an octahedral coordination, whereas when Rc/Ra= 0.732 – 1.000 you have a cubic coordination

```
  Rc/Ra space group
```

LiCl  0.42  Fm-3m

NaCl  0.56  Fm-3m

KCl   0.76  Fm-3m (Pm-3m under pressure)

RbCl  0.86  Fm-3m (Pm-3m under pressure)

CsCl  0.96  Pm-3m

It is clear how the coordination number changes as a function of the radius ratio (that is also dependent on the applied pressure).